# Removing missing categories from geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe that includes points where the x values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7. When I go to plot the data this is what ggplot2 gives me:

[image]

I only want to include the points mentioned above. How do I take out the instance of 5 and 6 in the bar plot?

(I have tried googling the answer and nothing is coming up with my actual need so I figured I'd ask the community which might give an answer sooner - please be kind I know this is bound to have a simple solution)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not a bioinformatics question and should be on stack overflow instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by converting the column in the dataframe to a character using this command:

`df$day <- as.character(df$day)`

and it worked like a charm! Thanks for your advice @haci

> You can give a try by converting the column of numbers to a factor variable.

[image]